# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class - in Jelly bean (4.2.2)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am getting this exception (ActivityNotFound) only on android 4.2.2, while starting an activity from a custom view.  This works fine on all devices which are 4.1.1 and below.

Has anyone faced similar issues with 4.2.2 ?

Code that starts the activity from my custom view

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRAS1, serializable);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRAS2, serializable);           
((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.MY_ACTION);
```

Stacktrace:

```
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sample.activity/com.sample.activity.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7461)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2186)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1516)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2134)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7641)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3676)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3607)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4802)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4781)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4873)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-04 16:58:29.715: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Should be something to do with casting context to `Activity`. Where are you calling this? What's the super class? Post your manifest also.

Comment: From a custom view extends ImageView. I also think its something to do with the casting, still trying few work arounds.

Comment: As the error message says, have you added the activity to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, it is in manifest and works on all devices with android version 4.1.1 and below. The issue is only with 4.2.2.

Comment: This is a weird case and i've noticed some issues on 4.2.2 too related to not being extremely explicit, did you try adding the "Default" category on the manifest:
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="action" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: I have found the issue and posted the answer, but it looks strange to me as it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was with the manifest,

I had this activity declared in manifest as,

```
 <activity android:name="com.sample.MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
         android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
         </activity>
```

It started working after removing the package reference from the declaration, like below,

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
             android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
             </activity>
```

I am not sure why would it behave this way only for this activity as I have other activities in my app declared with package reference and that works fine, Wierd though.

Comment: Apparently, the cause of this problem may not even be the manifest declaration. I have doubt it is some platform bug in API levels higher than ICS. But I couldn't find any clear evidence to support this.

Comment: I found a common thing between different cases reporting this same issue. It was seen mostly for `startActivityForResult()` and never reported for `startActivity()`. This is a bit of evidence pointing towards a platform bug.